# Copy files from a list while maintaining directory structure in Java

Tags: java, copy

I have searched and searched for an example of how to do this, but I have yet to find one.

I have a log file and in this log file it will have a list of files. I then need to move the files that were scanned in to a quarantined folder and retain directory structure. So far I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)   throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{  
    String logPath = "C:\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\build\\LogFiles\\DoScan.log";
    String safeFolder = "C:\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\build\\Quaratined";  
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( logPath ));
    String line = null;


    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'[a-zA-Z]:\\\\.+?'");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( line );

        if (matcher.matches()) 
        {
        }
        if (matcher.find()) 
        {
                String s = matcher.group(); 
                s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1); 
                files.add(new File(s));

                System.out.println("File found:" + files.get(files.size() - 1));
        }
    }



    for (File f : files) 
    {

        // Make sure we get a file indeed
            if (f.exists()) 
        {   
            if (!f.renameTo(new File(safeFolder, f.getName()))) 
            {
                        System.out.println("Moving file: " + f + " to " + safeFolder);
                        System.err.println("Unable to move file: " + f);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Could not find file: " + f);
        }
    }   
}
```

}

This works and successfully moves the files, but it does not maintain directory structure.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Whats the output of the "  System.out.println("File found:" + files.get(files.size() - 1));" ? Also from which "root" do you want to preserve your directory structure?

Comment: The log file will have something like this in it:


 [_1126]|Processing file 'C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\build\Plugins\File8.exe'.
[_1124]|Processing file 'C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\build\Plugins\JAR\File 1.txt'.
|Processing file 'C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\build\Plugins\JAR\File 2.txt'.

I'd like it to read that list, copy the files from that list and maintain the directory structure... so...

in the quarantined folder I would have

C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\build\Quarantined\File8.exe
C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\build\Quarantined\JAR\File 1.txt
C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\build\Quarantined\JAR\File 2.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String logPath = "/tmp/log";
    String safeFolder = "/tmp/q";
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logPath));
    String line = null;


    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            files.add(new File(line));

            System.out.println("File found:" + files.get(files.size() - 1));
    }

    String root = "/tmp/" ;

    for (File f : files && f.isFile()) {

        if (f.exists()) {
            File destFile = new File(safeFolder, f.getAbsolutePath().replace(root,""));
            destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            if (!f.renameTo(destFile)) {
                System.out.println("Moving file: " + f + " to " + safeFolder);
                System.err.println("Unable to move file: " + f);
            }
       } else {
            System.out.println("Could not find file: " + f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Though now the only problem is is it's moving the entire directory when it gets to 

15:29:17.696931 [_1118]|Processing directory 'C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\build\Plugins'.

I need it to only copy the actual files

Comment: You'll need to do one of 1) Use the regexp to match for "directory"/"file" 2) call f.isDirectory() to check if its a file or dir

Comment: Ahh cool. I like your solution better than what I had. Thanks again